# How refactor Apache POI create cells legacy code?

Tags: java, java-stream, apache-poi, legacy-code

I wrote simple method which generate excel file using data from Order class. I use createCell() method to put the data into this cells. createCell() method use identifier on which position of sheet I want to insert data. Is there a way to generate cells for each getter of Order class using java streams?

```
   private static void createCell(Order order, Product product, Row row) {

    Cell idCell = row.createCell(0);
    Cell dateCell = row.createCell(1);
    Cell destinationCell = row.createCell(2);
    Cell productCell = row.createCell(3);
    Cell productQuantityCell = row.createCell(4);

    idCell.setCellValue(order.getOrderID());
    dateCell.setCellValue(String.valueOf(order.getDate()));
    destinationCell.setCellValue(order.getDestination());
    productCell.setCellValue(product.getProductCode());
    productQuantityCell.setCellValue(product.getProductQuantity());
}
```

Comment: Do these getters have the same type, in other words, is it really the same `setCellValue` method you’re invoking five times? Trying to rewrite this using streams is as useful as trying to rewrite this using a loop, which you apparently didn’t consider. When you remove the local variables and just chain the methods, like `row.createCell(0).setCellValue(order.getOrderID());` you end up with just five statements. Simple and straight-forward.

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/ozlerhakan/poiji ?

Comment: @PJFanning i didnt know about this library, thanx